# Crypto trading bot with Binance, Error from callback > bound method, when I am trying to get historical candles from Binance using the "GET" method

Tags: python, websocket, callback, binance, cryptocurrency

The bot takes certain data from [www.testnet.binancefuture.com](http://www.testnet.binancefuture.com) the information I am getting are bid and ask, historical candles, contracts, balances, place, cancel and order status. The callback methods are `on_open`, `on_error`, `on_close` and `on_message` + Channel subscription. Here is the code and the error:

```
class BinanceFuturesClient:

    def __init__(self, public_key, secret_key, testnet):
        if testnet:
            self.base_url = "https://testnet.binancefuture.com"
            self.wss_url = "wss://stream.binancefuture.com/ws"
        else:
            self.base_url = "https://fapi.binance.com"
            self.wss_url = "wss://fstream.binance.com/ws"

        self.public_key = public_key
        self.secret_key = secret_key

        self.headers = {'X-MBX-APIKEY': self.public_key}

        self.prices = dict()

        self.id = 1
        self.ws = None

        t = threading.Thread(target=self.start_ws)
        t.start()

        logger.info("Binance Futures Client successfully initialized")

    def generate_signature(self, data):
        return hmac.new(self.secret_key.encode(), urlencode(data).encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

    def make_request(self, method, endpoint, data):
        if method == "GET":
            response = requests.get(self.base_url + endpoint, params=data, headers=self.headers)
        elif method == 'POST':
            response = requests.post(self.base_url + endpoint, params=data, headers=self.headers)
        elif method == 'DELETE':
            response = requests.delete(self.base_url + endpoint, params=data, headers=self.headers)
        else:
            raise ValueError()

        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.json()
        else:
            logger.error('Error while making %s request to %s: %s(error code %s)',
                         method, endpoint, response.json(), response.status_code)
            return None

    def get_contracts(self):
        exchange_info = self.make_request("GET", "/fapi/v1/exchangeInfo", None)

        contracts = dict()

        if exchange_info is not None:
            for contract_data in exchange_info['symbols']:
                contracts[contract_data['pair']] = contract_data

        return contracts

    def get_historical_candles(self, symbol, interval):
        data = dict()
        data['symbol'] = symbol
        data['interval'] = interval
        data['limit'] = 1000

        raw_candles = self.make_request("GET", "/fapi/v1/klines", data)

        candles = []

        if raw_candles is not None:
            for c in raw_candles:
                candles.append([c[0], float(c[1]), float(c[2]), float(c[3]), float(c[4]), float(c[5])])

        return candles

    def get_bid_ask(self, symbol):
        data = dict()
        data['symbol'] = symbol
        ob_data = self.make_request("GET", "/fapi/v1/ticker/bookTicker", data)

        if ob_data is not None:
            if symbol not in self.prices:
                self.prices[symbol] = {'bid': float(ob_data['bidPrice']), 'ask': float(ob_data['askPrice'])}
            else:
                self.prices[symbol]['bid'] = float(ob_data['bidPrice'])
                self.prices[symbol]['ask'] = float(ob_data['askPrice'])

            return self.prices[symbol]

    def get_balances(self):
        data = dict()
        data['timestamp'] = int(time.time() * 1000)
        data['signature'] = self.generate_signature(data)

        balances = dict()

        account_data = self.make_request("GET", "/fapi/v1/account", data)

        if account_data is not None:
            for a in account_data['assets']:
                balances[a['asset']] = a

        return balances

    def place_order(self, symbol, side, quantity, order_type, price=None, tif=None):
        data = dict()
        data['symbol'] = symbol
        data['side'] = side
        data['quantity'] = quantity
        data['type'] = order_type

        if price is not None:
            data['price'] = price

        if tif is not None:
            data['timeInForce'] = tif

        data['timestamp'] = int(time.time() * 1000)
        data['signature'] = self.generate_signature(data)

        order_status = self.make_request("POST", "/fapi/v1/order", data)

        return order_status

    def cancel_order(self, symbol, order_id):
        data = dict()
        data['symbol'] = symbol
        data['orderId'] = order_id

        data['timestamp'] = int(time.time() * 1000)
        data['signature'] = self.generate_signature(data)

        order_status = self.make_request("DELETE", "/fapi/v1/order", data)

        return order_status

    def get_order_status(self, symbol, order_id):
        data = dict()
        data['timestamp'] = int(time.time() * 1000)
        data['symbol'] = symbol
        data['orderId'] = order_id
        data['signature'] = self.generate_signature(data)

        order_status = self.make_request("GET", "/fapi/v1/order", data)

        return order_status

    def start_ws(self):
        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(self.wss_url, on_open=self.on_open, on_close=self.on_close,
                                    on_error=self.on_error, on_message=self.on_message)

        ws.run_forever()

    def on_close(self, ws):
        logger.warning("Binance websocket connection closed")

    def on_error(self, ws, msg):
        logger.error("Binance connection error: %s", msg)

    def on_open(self, ws):
        logger.info("Binance connection opened")

        self.subscribe_channel("BTCUSDT")

    def on_message(self, ws, msg):
        print(msg)

    def subscribe_channel(self, symbol):
        data = dict()
        data['method'] = "SUBSCRIBE"
        data['params'] = []
        data['params'].append(symbol.lower() + "@bookTicker")
        data['id'] = self.id

        print(data, type(data))
        print(json.dumps(data), type(json.dumps(data)))

        self.ws.send(json.dumps(data))

        self.id += 1
```

The error after data:

> 2021-05-04 16:51:55,683 INFO :: Binance Futures Client successfully initialized
> {'method': 'SUBSCRIBE', 'params': ['btcusdt@bookTicker'], 'id': 1} <class 'dict'>
> {"method": "SUBSCRIBE", "params": ["btcusdt@bookTicker"], "id": 1} <class 'str'>
> 2021-05-04 16:51:56,833 INFO :: Binance connection opened
> 2021-05-04 16:51:56,834 ERROR :: error from callback <bound method
> BinanceFuturesClient.on_open of <connectors.binance_futures.BinanceFuturesClient object at 0x000001CAD7F712E0>>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revise your code as follows;

```
def start_ws(self):
self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(self.wss_url, on_open=self.on_open, on_close=self.on_close,
                            on_error=self.on_error, on_message=self.on_message)

self.ws.run_forever()
```